# Can I specify a repository structure with a single Cargo.toml but multiple versions of the code, each with separate main.rs files?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm writing a book about embedded Rust using `mdbook` as one git repository and then I have another repository created by `cargo` where I place the code.

I'd like to structure the code so it corresponds with the chapters in the book and therefore is in separate directory.

The structure for the book:

```
├── book
├── book.toml
└── src
    ├── chapter_1.md
    ├── chapter_2.md
    ├── chapter_3.md
    ├── chapter_4.md
    ├── chapter_5.md
    ├── chapter_6.md
    └── SUMMARY.md
```

And the structure for the code:

```
├── aarch64-unknown-none.json
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
├── layout.ld
├── Readme.md
├── chapter1
│   └── main.rs
├── chapter2
│   ├── boot.rs
│   └── main.rs
└── chapter3
    ├── boot.rs
    ├── console.rs
    └── main.rs
```

I'd prefer this structure as the reader can then look directly at the code for the chapter and not search git commits. I also sometimes need to modify something later therefore git commits are not a solution.

Is there a way to specify this format in Cargo.toml? To either build all the directories or specify which one on the command line.

Comment: Have you looked at [workspaces](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html#the-workspace-section)?

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: You should go ahead and self-answer with an example of how it can be used in that case.

Answer (score 2):

The exact solution can be found in the [second edition of the Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch14-03-cargo-workspaces.html) with an example.

I restructured the repository like this:

```
├── aarch64-unknown-none.json
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
├── layout.ld
├── Readme.md
├── chapter1
│   ├── Cargo.toml
│   └── main.rs
├── chapter2
│   ├── boot.rs
│   ├── Cargo.toml
│   └── main.rs
└── chapter3
    ├── boot.rs
    ├── Cargo.toml
    ├── console.rs
    └── main.rs
```

`Cargo.toml` files in the *chapter* directories remain without any modification. Only the `Cargo.toml` in the root is modified to contain the following:

```
[workspace]
members = ["chapter1", "chapter2", "chapter3"]
```

One small drawback to this solution is that the members must have different crate names in their `Cargo.toml` as the output of all members is stored in the `target` dir in the root of the workspace. This is only a small issue and I appreciate the flexibility Cargo offers.